# Google Spreadsheet conditional formatting script based on time duration

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I was wondering if there is a way to have conditional formatting based on duration of time; for example lets say I want to look at a timestamp. and if it's been longer than 24 hours from said timestamp the cell will turn the color of red, but if it's under that 24 hour period it will turn the cell the color of green.

Can this be done? .. Thoughts?

Thanks in advance / Kind Regards,

-Sean D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the menu `Format` > `Conditional formating...` >
you can select the option `date is`, `date is before`, `date is after` apply a condition `today`, `tomorrow`, `exact date`... and then apply a color to these conditions
So in your case you need to apply a color that will be by defect green and add a conditional formating that say if the timestamp is over yesterday then apply color red
**EDIT**

to compare two timestamp, you can also use the above trick, with a little modifications:
you need to tag in red the cell if it have "!". In the cell, write this formula: `=if(E3-E4>1;E3;TEXT(E3;"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")&" !")` with E3 and E4 the cell where you wrote the two timestamp. you can hide the cell E3 to avoid having the result in duplicate.
otherwise, you'll need to set an app script in your spreadsheet for example:

```
function compareDate(){
  var ts1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E3").getValue();
  var ts2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E4").getValue();
  var time1=new Date(ts1).getTime();
  var time2=new Date(ts2).getTime();
  if((time1+86400000)<time2){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E3").setBackground("red");
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer, I think what I need is a little more complicated though =( , I have a final duration of an order, so let's say Jill started an order at 11:00 am, and company policy states that the order has to be processed within 24 hours of purchase, now an "active matrix" like your example is great and will work for that part.  I also have an archive sheet for which let's say Jill completes the order in 2 hours, she enters certain text in a field which copies that row to the archive sheet, now after it get's copied I want to change the conditional formatting to show that if the order.......

Comment: ...... took longer than 24 hours that it would have a red background.. do you understand what I am saying? I don't want to compare my archives to the current date or time but base it off a total duration.

Comment: @SeanD. Changed the answer to take in account two timestamps